# Should a windows 2003 Terminal Server be set to optimise performance for forground or background tasks?

Tags: windows-server-2003, terminal-server

I note that the default setting is foreground not background tasks.

Which setting is best for a terminal server with many clients?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foreground.  There was some conjecture when Windows 2000 was the current os about using background, but it is definitely foreground now.

Comment: +1. The purpose of having a TS is for hosting and running user applications, which 9 out of 10 times are foreground tasks.

Comment: Thanks for that. What made me not sure about that was a contrary recommendation I read somewhere else.  Given that lots of apps are running in virtual sessions, is TS smart enough to know what is foreground?

Comment: @Matt - I definitely remember a Windows 2000 terminal server recommendation to use background.  However, since the setting changes from background to Programs on Windows 2003 when terminal services is added, I would say Microsoft changed something in the os so that this is now the recommended setting. (Or the original recommendation was wrong ;-)

Comment: Even back on NT4 the prevailing wisdom was to ignore Microsoft's recommendation and actually test it both ways. Then choose the option that performs best for your particular use case. I see no real reason not to continue doing that today.